# Facebook PHP SDK rights

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

i am currently working on an autoposter app to publish content on my own fanpages. This is the only function the app is going to be used for. My personal profile will be the only user of the app.
I have read through the documentation for developers but I still have trouble figuring this out.
From what I understand I don't have to submit the app for review to facebook if I only need the manage_pages right.
How does this work for an app that will only be used by me? Do I still have to submit it to facebook to be able to use the manage_pages and publish_pages permission? Or is there a way around that?

Comment: If you are still able to grant those permissions to your app once it is in “live” mode, then this would work without submitting it for review.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sadly i can not get either one of the permissions as soon as the app is live. It only works in dev mode.

Comment: Well then you will have to submit for review, so that you can grant those permissions to the app in live mode.